Problem with VS Code er. 1.95.3 message pwsh.exe noexit
While using the VSC application for phyton I encountered an error:
Command line:
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe '-noexit' '-command' 'try { . "c:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\contrib\terminal\common\scripts\shellIntegration.ps1" } catch {}' .

Phyton applications start without problems but I always get this message. What should I do about it? I don't understand it. Please help.
Software versions:

Windows 11 Pro 24H2
VSC 1.95.3
Powershell 7.4.6

